# SQL scripts getting corrupted while opening objects using schema browser in oracle SQL developer 1.5.5

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I open code for large objects like package bodies from tree list in Oracle SQL Developer 1.5.5, the lines of codes in script are getting mixed and the object is getting invalid.
I am getting the correct script without issue while opening using `select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('object_type','object_name') from dual`.
Kindly help me with a solution.

Comment: Which database version are you using ? That sql developer ( 1.5.5 ) is a very old version from 2008. Upgrade to the latest version of SQL Developer and you won't have any issue of that kind.  I mean, it is a free software, so why not having the latest version

Comment: 1.5.5? Did you consider **upgrading** SQL Developer? The latest version is 20.2 so - maybe your problems will be solved in a matter of a few clicks.